# Update binding when nested object changes

Tags: wpf, object, binding, nested

I have a some XAML as follows (a simple Label and Button):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Path=TestPerson}">
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"></Label>
    <Button Content="Button" Click="button1_Click" />
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

in the code behind I have:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _person = new Person();
    public Person TestPerson { get { return _person; } }

    public MainWindow()
    {           
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _person.Name = "Bill";
        //_person = new Person() { Name = "Bill" };
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestPerson"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and the class Person is:

```
public class Person
{
    string _name = "Bob";

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}
```

As it is, firing the Propertychanged event does not cause the Label's contents to change to Bill.

I've found I am able to overcome this by either:

- Assigning a new object to _person (as in the commented out line)
- Removing the DataContext from the StackPanel and have Label bind to Path=TestPerson.Name

I don't understand why I have to actually assign a NEW object to _person for the Label to update, or use the FULL path in the binding.

Is there a way to update the Label *without* supplying the full path (relying on the DataContext), and *without* assigning a new object to _person?

Answer (score 4):

You raise `PropertyChanged` for the `Person` instance `TestPerson`. However, `TestPerson` hasn't changed, it is the `Name` property of `TestPerson` that has changed and that is the property the `Label` is binding to.

**Edit:** To answer why your first two versions work

> Assigning a new object to _person (as in the commented out line)

Here you are actually changing the value of `TestPerson` and because `DataContext` is inherited by the children, the `Label` gets a new `DataContext` as well so that's why the `Binding` is updated.

> Removing the DataContext from the StackPanel and have Label bind to
>   Path=TestPerson.Name

This is something I've never seen. The same binding subscribes to `PropertyChanged` for both `TestPerson` and `Name` in `Person` so raising `PropertyChanged` for any of these properties will work.

If you want to overcome this without implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `Person`, you can change set `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit`

```
<Label Name="label"
       Content="{Binding Path=Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
```

And update the `Binding` manually whenever `Name` changes

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _person.Name = "Bill";
    BindingExpression be = label.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
    be.UpdateTarget();
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestPerson"));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for `Person` as well and it will work

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{ 
    string _name = "Bob"; 

    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return _name; } 
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        } 
    } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I think I might have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for each property in Person...

Comment: Meant to edit my comment above to this: The example I gave is somewhat contrived; my real code has a custom UserControl in place of the Label, and my equivalent of the Person class has something like 10 properties. I wanted a UserControl capable of displaying (and updating) all the Person properties but without all 10 properties using INotifyPropertyChanged, but I guess that's not possible. It's no big headache, but I like to understand why things don't work :)

Comment: Updated my answer with some details on why your two other versions work. I've never noticed the behavior of the last one (binding to `TestPerson.Name`) and I actually didn't expect this to work for both properties but apparently it did :) +1 for that finding

Answer (score 0):

You need a little change in your XAML...

In your code behind, instead of setting `DataContext` as `this`, set it in XAML via Binding...

```
     <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                            AncestorType= {x:Type Window},
                                                Mode=FindAncestor}, 
                                       Path=TestPerson}">
          <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"></Label>
          <Button Content="Button" Click="button1_Click" />
     </StackPanel>
```

Remove the

```
     DataContext = this;
```

from your code behind.

Let me know if this helps.